# Pyspark dropping all connections

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to diagnose some weird connection issues on my spark grid: I'm seeing an insane number of dropped connection.

I'm running something that looks like this on a distributed pyspark cluster

```
spark_context.parallelize(tasks)) \
                .map(lambda kwargs: my_mapped_fn(**kwargs) \
                .reduceByKey(my_reduce_by_key) \
                .map(lambda (x,y): (x, my_final_map(x,y))) \
                .reduce(my_final_reduce)
```

I'm pretty sure it fails during the my_final_map part, hence my suspicion about the closure transport, so many that my jobs fail.

Here is the error i get:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to 10.12.9.117:38103
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:120)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:579)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: 10.12.9.117:38103
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:640)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: why do you execute "collect()" at the end of the call?

Comment: please share the error you get, the amount of data you are trying to process, the size of your cluster. The source of the problem **might be** the 'collect()' which send a huge amount of data to the driver.

Comment: Hey @Yaron, thank you for your help! I double checked, i switched the collect to a reduce step and remove the local variable. Still seeing the errors thought :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this useful, the actual answer was completely unrelated to spark. In fact ip address lookup on some of the nodes was broken.